# react, To call a function from a child component to a parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to run a function on the parent component in the child component.
Eventually, I want to have the function run when the scroll goes to that position.

UseImperativeHandle was used, but props did not apply. Is there a way to apply props in the useImperativeHandle?
Also, is it correct to use IntersectionObserver this way?

child Components

```
function Percent(props, ref) {

    useImperativeHandle(ref,() => ({
            percentst: () => {
            var cnt = document.querySelectorAll(".count")[props.num];
            var water = document.querySelectorAll(".water")[props.num];
            var percent = cnt.innerText;
            var interval;
            interval = setInterval(function () {
                percent++;
                cnt.innerHTML = percent;
                water.style.transform = 'translate(0' + ',' + (100 - percent) + '%)';
                if (percent == props.percent) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                }
            }, 80);
        }
    }));
}
export default forwardRef(Percent);
```

parent component

```
function About(props) {
    const containerRef = useRef();
    const myRef = useRef();
    const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);

    const callbackFunction = (entries) => {
        const [entry] = entries;
        setIsVisible(entry.isIntersecting);
    };

    const options = {
        root: document.getElementById('skills'),
        rootMargin: '0px',
        threshold: 1
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callbackFunction, options);
        
        console.log(containerRef.current)
        if (containerRef.current) observer.observe(containerRef.current);

        return () => {
            myRef.current.percentst()
            if (containerRef.current) observer.unobserve(containerRef.current);
        };
    }, [containerRef, options]);

return(
<div ref={containerRef}></div>
<Percent ref={myRef} />
)
}
export default About;
```

Comment: Could you pass the function directly to the child component? Something like `<Percent callback={nameOfTheFunction}>`. That makes it available as `props.callback` in the child component.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways of doing this

- Pass your method as a prop to the child (this may not be desirable)
- Use custom event listeners/triggers

There are some packages out there that will help with events such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-custom-events